Grafana with Infinity plugin with bearer token
I'm using the Infinity plugin for Grafana the problem is the api I am trying to use first requires me to get a bearer token.
For example using this CLI:
curl --location 'https://serverIpAddress/auth/login' \
     --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     --data-raw '{
         "username": "userName",
         "password": "passWord"
     }' \
     --insecure

Then returns :
{"data":{"access_token":"eYtNGVjYS05OD....","refresh_token":"16248292...f"},"metadata":{}}
Only AFTER I get back the access_token can actually make my API call.

I coudn't find in any of the documentation on how to first ask for the bearer token then submit the quest

The OAauth2 auth type for the Infinity Plugin first retrieves the access token like you're describing, but only for the official OAuth2 specification with x-www-form-urlencoded data, not application/json.
If you cannot change the API's login flow, you'd have to fork the Infinity plugin to create your own Grafana data source.
